# In Python, is there any way to explicitly show that you're overriding an inherited class variable?

Tags: python

Example:

```
class A:
    x = 1


class B(A):
    x = 2
```

In this code snippet, if class A and B were defined in separate files, there wouldn't be any way for the person reading class B to know that the class variable 'x' was inherited from class A, and that it's being overwritten. Is there any way (other than leaving a comment) to make this obvious to the reader?

Comment: Why would it be important for someone to know that?

Comment: Which IDE are you use?

Comment: I don't use an IDE, I sublime. And the reason it's important is because e.g. the way you configure the Django Admin is by overriding any combination of about 150 different class variables and methods. But when people start putting their own code in the admin models, it's hard to know which statements are doing magical Django things versus which are purely user code. It would be 10x easier to understand the code if there were a way to make it explicit which methods were overriding something in the Django ModelAdmin parent class.

Comment: PyCharm will show you want on the left side of the variable.

Comment: Ok but if I don't want to use an IDE, is there a way to make this clear just using Python? If a language makes code difficult to read if you're not using an IDE, that's a problem in the language that should be remediated somehow.

Comment: If you don't want to comment, than no. Why would their be another way ? A comment doesn't cost you anything.

Comment: Because it's harder to get people to agree that it's a best practice to leave a comment as part of a style guide, and to standardize that behavior. It would be much easier if there were a way to just do something like ```from A: x = 2``` instead, so as to signal in code that ```x``` was originally set on the parent class.

Comment: I agree @Sk Ker said, the problem is are you accept write another code for check it, if you do the way, in technically it's a waste.

Comment: The kind of syntax I'm proposing could be purely optional (so no performance hit in cases where there are no benefits). The only thing it would do is raise an error if the thing in question wasn't defined in the place where the code said it was defined.

Comment: You can choose different style for naming user-defined variable ex. If variables inherited are `x,y,z` then you can use `u_x, u_y, u_z` for customized variables